# Naming classes that make a single calculation or decision

Tags: oop, naming

I find myself from time to time writing classes that their only responsibility is to do a single calculation or make a single decision.
These classes usually have a single public method that's performing the calculation/decision logic.

I am currently struggling with naming these classes. I started with adding a "Helper" suffix (e.g. DiscountHelper), but I really don't like it.

How do you name this type of classes?

Comment: Well what does the class? `DiscountCalculator` might be more appropriate, or `DiscountFactory` if you're actually returning objects.

Comment: Well, that depends what you're doing. Although a single method that does a single calculation may be a bit *too* narrow for a single object. Can you describe what you're doing exactly?

Comment: This increasingly happens to me as well, in which case the logical consequence is to ditch OO and pick up FP: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/03/10/solid-the-next-step-is-functional

Comment: @jeroen-vannevel and Second Rikudo it happens to me with all kinds of classes that have a single responsibility. For example, a class that has a logic that checks if a client is eligible for a discount, I'll name it EligibleDiscountHelper.

Comment: @MarkSeemann I read the article. He is describing exactly what I encountered, but unfortunately I can't just move to F# and using a lot of closures in C# is not a good idea.